# Java returning error: expected an int but got a string

Tags: spring, rest

Struggling with this error but cant find the obvious datatype mistakes that would usually cause it I have attached the relevant code.

The error:

```
TypeMismatchException: id of the wrong type com.example.demo.models.Hires. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String hid;
```

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{hid}")
    public Hires getHires(@PathVariable String hid) {
        return hs.getHireById(hid).get();
```

```
public Optional<Hires> getHireById(String hid) {
        return hr.findById(hid);
```

If anyone can spot what might be causing this it would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the string parameter hid, see:

the method:

```
public Optional<Hires> getHireById(String hid) {
    return hr.findById(hid);
}
```

It is receiving a String hid, it should be int hid instead, because you are finding by id, and the id is a int.

But you want to find by hid, so you have to create a method in your repository like this:

```
public Optional<Hires> findByHid(String hid)
```

Then you can use like this:

```
public Optional<Hires> getHireById(String hid) {
    return hr.findByHid(hid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rhadamez, unfortunately it is a string I am searching for "hid". Its not incorrectly labelled.

Comment: So, you have to change your method findById to findByHid in your repository, then it will work. Also, I have updated the answer according your commentary.

Comment: Rhadamez you're a lifesaver thanks a million! I cant cast a vote unfortunately